# Access MAMP Site on LAN

Tags: macos, networking, development

The senior developer just left our company and I didn't have a chance to ask him how he did the following:

At my company we use the hostname "molly.local" in our local development area. We are serving up our files through MAMP, however this is obviously not how every computer connects to the the host name "molly.local". I've checked a few computer's host files in */etc/hosts* and none of them have been set up to point to the serving computer's IP.

So before I go around to all of the computers in work and all the subsequent new computers the company buys, how do I set up the new host name to be accessible like the current host name is?

I've tried to set up an HTTP proxy on the router and not had much luck.

Comment: Not sure to understand the question, but you don't have a DNS server to resolve molly.local ?

Comment: @chaput I have been strenuously looking around and found no such DNS server to resolve the molly.local host name.